# Ensure folder packed into nuget is extracted

Tags: .net-core, nuget

I'm trying to include a directory `Textures` with image files  (`.bmp`, `.png` etc) in a `nuget` package.
I have managed to get it in the `.nupkg` file by doing the following in my `.csproj` file for the library being packed:

```
<Target Name="CopyTextures" AfterTargets="PostBuild">
        <ItemGroup>           
            <Textures Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\Textures\**\*.*" />
            <None Include="@(Textures)">
                <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
                <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
                <Pack>true</Pack>
                <PackagePath>.\Textures</PackagePath>
            </None>
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
```

The above happens after the `PostBuild` target because that target creates the `Textures` directory in `$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)`.

If I examine the .nupkg file with 7zip, there is a `Textures` directory with the contents I expect inside it, happy days (it has taken me a while to get to this point..)

But - there's nothing in the `.nuspec` file referencing the `Textures` directory, I think this might be why it isn't being extracted?

I have a test application that references the nuget package, and would like to see `Textures` get extracted into the build location of that project (currently `projectName\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1`).

Ideally I'd do this all from the `.csproj` of the packaged library, but open to suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

The following is working for me:

```
     <Target Name="CopyTextures" AfterTargets="PostBuild">
        <ItemGroup>           
            <Textures Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\Textures\**\*.*" />
            <Content Include="@(Textures)">
                <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
                <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
                <DeploymentContent>true</DeploymentContent>
                <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
                <Pack>true</Pack>
            </Content>
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
```

It's also really important to clear the nuget cache between builds! I was manually (via a script) deleting the actual cached package file, but it wasn't enough to get this to update properly.
To be doubly sure I commit each change to git so I get a different version number.